# How can I wrap borders partway around three sides of an element?

Tags: html, css, border

I need a complex border for an anchor element. Unfortunately I can only solve the whole thing with CSS classes of the anchor element because I don't have any options for the layout.

I already tested it with background linear-gradient but I didn't reach a satisfactory result.

Here is an image as it should look, regardless of the font size and length of the text.

[image]

```css
:root {
  --gb-nav-btn-color-hover: red;
}

a {
  border-radius: 0px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--gb-nav-btn-color-hover) 2px, transparent 2px) 2px 0px, linear-gradient(to left, var(--gb-nav-btn-color-hover) 2px, green 2px) 0px -7px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center, center;
}
```

```html
<a href="">An anchor element</a>
```

Comment: FYI, tags can't have borders. They're just markup text in a file. _Elements_ are what you style with CSS.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some HTML as well. Put it all in a demo using the editor. You should also tag HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to the rescue. I've used `em` units (per [Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan)'s helpful reminder) to keep the various aspects of the design in proportion to the font size.

Also, I've put some common values in [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) for easy configuration.

```css
:root {
  --descender-height: 0.215em;
  --end-padding: 0.45em;
  --border-width: 0.07em;
}

a.fancy {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: black;
  padding-right: var(--end-padding);
  border-top: var(--border-width) solid;
  position: relative;
}

a.fancy::before,
a.fancy::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: var(--border-width);
  height: calc(100% - var(--descender-height));
  right: 0;
}

a.fancy::after {
  width: var(--end-padding);
  height: var(--border-width);
  bottom: var(--descender-height);
}

a.fancy.small {
  font-size: 32px;
}

a.fancy.very-small {
  font-size: 24px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="fancy">An anchor element</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="" class="fancy small">An anchor element</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="" class="fancy very-small">An anchor element</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-left: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: solid 3px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 30px;
}

.box__link {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-left: -2.5px;
}

.box__link::after {
  width: 28px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-right: solid 3px black;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -6.5px;
  margin-bottom: -0.2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="box__link">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 0; 
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: black;
}

a::before,
a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px; 
  background: black;
}

a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a>Home</a>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi,not realy.

The top border should be left aligned with the text. The bottom border should start directly at the end of the text and be baseline with the text.

Exactly like in the picture.

Comment: Have you seen the example before answering? How is your code any similar to the image OP provided?

Comment: @user23298913 Now check I have modified the answer